# What kind of LC circuit can produce this response?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf

I am trying to come up with an equivalent circuit for a structure that I'm working on. The response is shown below:

[image: Impedance Vs. Loaded Capacitor]

The modelling of the structure hasn't incorporated any loss, therefore the real part of the impedance is 0. I am not a circuit expert, and would like some pointers on what kind of circuits would be capable in producing a response like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPoH66.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-filt-hipass-af.html

DIY java simulator

This circuit applies to all crystals, ceramic resonators , SAWs and some ceramic caps

Here 30nH is a short length of wire and C2, 0.1pF is 10x bigger than cap which determines series resonance C1

... from any frequency e.g. from kHz to GHz

Low frequency Xtals are in the Henry range but still fempto-farad [fF] for the "motional capacitance"

### Update after some effort on my part.

A 4th order LC filter can be made to the reverse pole zero shape.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is C1 or C2 the tunable capacitor?

Comment: Could you please point me to some resources that discuss the behaviors of such crystals? Thanks!

Also, in my simulation, the impedance first decrease rapidly then increase - this circuit and most other ones I've tried seem to do the opposite.

Comment: maybe you should show your equation to see if it is real or "imaginary" {pun intended}

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer my question, and the circuit you show doesn't have the same behaviour I described.

Comment: not possible without your formula

Comment: it could be a reactive loaded delay line using 1/4 wave transformer

Comment: Thanks! I don't have a formula because it was obtained from simulation and I wanted to map the response to a circuit, your answer was great help!